# How to pack current state of OS?

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm, distributions

I'm planning to install CentOS and fill it with applications curated to and revolving around my workflow. But I also don't want to install those applications every time I have to install it on a new machine. Basically a private distro.

Let's assume that preference (`/home/` and stuffs) files will be not packed, and will be free to be created by users I (if ever) distribute to.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to "describe" the system. E.g. using Ansible playbook. User then can change few variables or templates and have its own instance.